# Confusing about Resolution and Screen size in MobileDevice, can we design mobile Website that has Gui enlarged according to screen size?obile

Tags: gwt

Ok, now most mordern smartphone has 720p or 1080p resolution. That mean even screen size is small like 4 in, we still can see all text, gui (such as email textbox) of the whole website when first time opening it in Galaxy s3.

However, though we can see the very little email textbox in mobile browser, it is too small for us to enter data. So we need to magnify the page and that is very time consuming.

My question is, can we make the gui of GWT app automatically enlarges itself so that mobile users do not need to enlarge it?

Also the gwt could shpw the gui in Portrait direction.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow responsive web design principles to achieve your objective. Also have a look here [bootstrap provides widgets that are flexible](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap)